# How to achieve ItemSelection and IsMouseOver effect in ItemsControl WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, itemscontrol

I am using `ItemsControl` in my application, applied `ItemTemplate` and `ItemsPanelTemplate` to it with a `ScrollViewer` style. All is fine. Binding is working pretty fine but here the issue: I want to select an item in `ItemsControl` but I am not able to do so as we do in `ListBox` using `IsSelected` property in triggers.

How can I achieve item selection and `IsMouseOver` in `ItemsControl` similar to `ListBox`, is there any way, as I did not find any resource on net useful enough so thought to ask for some help here.

Comment: Why not use a Selector or ListBox?

Comment: Typically I use a `ListBox` if I want item selection capabilities in WPF, and simply overwrite the `ItemTemplate` and possibly `ItemsPanelTemplate` or `ControlTemplate` to make it look the way I want. Its easier than trying to recreate the selection capabilities in an `ItemsControl`

Comment: Yes i finally replaced it with ListBox it worked. Thanks for reply Julien